# UltraWebGrid in Chrome works on one server, but not another

Tags: infragistics, ultrawebgrid

I have the *same* code on a stage server as on a production server. In Chrome on production the grid displays properly. On the stage server, the grid does not render correctly. What might cause this?

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Infragistics35.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.v8.3, Version=8.3.20083.1009, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb"
Namespace="Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebGrid" TagPrefix="igtbl" %>

<igtbl:UltraWebGrid ID="grdSearchResult" runat="server" Width="100%" ....
```

Comment: Wow, that is a seven year old version of Infragistics. Sounds like something else is interfering, but then again, there have been a lot of updates/fixes to the platform. Any chance to upgrade to the latest 15.1?

Comment: Yeah, it's some ancient legacy site that is still in use. They won't be upgrading, but thanks for the comment